# Why is `as.Date()` giving different results on different days for the same code?

Tags: r, as.date

[Screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahfkT.png)

I ran the first two lines of code in the screenshot and got one result. When I ran the same code today (the last two lines of code), I got a different result.

I expected to get the same result, but got a different one. Am I doing something wrong that I could not notice?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code/output/text in general.

Comment: Please read the documentation about how to use code blocks, and well formatting of a question

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for the `%V` format specifier](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) says

> (Accepted but ignored on input.)

What this means is that you can specify `%V` when *formatting* dates; but when *parsing* (i.e. *reading*) a date from a string, this format specifier is simply ignored. The result is thus the same as if you had written:

```
as.Date('2009', '%Y')
```

In which case the function fills in the missing components of the date (i.e. the month and day) from the *current* date, which obviously changes from day to day.

In other words: parsing a date expressed in terms of the week number is not supported by this function.